# How to skip particular column's values where they are empty in FlatFileItemReader<T>?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-batch

When I read the CSV file in Spring Batch, it throws BindException (typeMismatch) in the row, when there is no actual value for a particular column.

How to skip them?

Comment: can you post your stacktrace and also sample input file contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I configured my ItemReader like in the folowing:

**Spring Config:**

```
@Bean
Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .listener(dataProcessor)
            .chunk(100)
            .faultTolerant()
            .reader(yourReader()).faultTolerant().skipPolicy(new ItemVerificationSkipper())
            .processor(dataProcessor)
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
}
```

The important part is to add a skipPolicy:

```
reader(yourReader()).faultTolerant().skipPolicy(new ItemVerificationSkipper())
```

**ItemVerificationSkipper.java**

```
@Slf4j
public class ItemVerificationSkipper implements SkipPolicy {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkip(Throwable exception, int skipCount) throws SkipLimitExceededException {

            StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder();
            errorMessage
                    .append("Unexpected exception ")
                    .append(exception.toString())
//                    .append(ExceptionUtils.getStackFrames(exception))
                    .append("\n");
            log.error("{}", errorMessage.toString());
            return true;
    }

}
```

Edit after further comments:

RowMapper implementation needed for column value skipping:

**Config:**

```
itemReader.setRowMapper(new CustomRowMapper());
```

**CustomRowMapper.java**

```
public class CustomRowMapper implements RowMapper<YourClass> {

    @Override
    public YourClass mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        String columnXYZ = rs.getString("yourColumnName");
        //check input etc..

    }
}
```

Comment: But, won't this skip entire row/record? what I'm looking for is to skip reading the particular column's value, if there is no value. Currently, spring batch throws exception when it's (for example):

`firstname,surname,age (next row) john,martins,34 (next row) ,dorhpan, 32` (notice, that name value is missing here)

In this case, batch processor should just continue reading other values and read this empty value as empty (set nothing)

Comment: Well, this works for the whole row. If you want to handle certain column values you have to check your `RowMapper` implementation, as there you read out all single column values.

Comment: Point is, that I don't wanna skip entire row. If row number X doesn't have a value in column Y, I just wanna skip that value.. so that Spring doesn't throw exception but read the rest of record/row. I don't have any rowMapper implementations.

Comment: Ok, I added an example on how to do that with a row mapper.

Comment: Thank you, however, I'm afraid, it's not the method available in FlatFileItemReader.. it's rather JDBC stuff..

Comment: Well, but you can adapt and use `setLineMapper` :)